# Create New SharePoint Group Programmatically

Tags: development, groups

How can I create a new SharePoint group by code?

Answer (score 10):

```
SPWeb root = site.RootWeb;
SPGroup group = null;

// Check if the group exists
try
{                                     
    group = root.SiteGroups["The Group Name"];
}
catch { }

// If it doesn't, add it
if (group == null)
{
    root.SiteGroups.Add("The Group Name", member, root.Author, "Your Group Description");
    group = root.SiteGroups["The Group Name"];

    // Add the group's permissions
    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = root.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
    root.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    root.Update();
}
```

Comment: Is there compulsory  to update the root (root.update()) in the end ?

Comment: @DipenShah Try it without and see if it persists :)

Answer (score 4):

Creating the group is simple just call [SPGroupCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroupcollection.add.aspx)

```
using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
{
    SPGroupCollection collGroups = oWebsiteRoot.SiteGroups;
    SPUser oUser = oWebsiteRoot.Users["User_Name"];
    SPMember oMember = oWebsiteRoot.Users["User_Name"];

    collGroups.Add("Group_Name", oMember, oUser, "Description");
}
```

Then you need may need to add users/groups and permissions depending on your needs

Comment: The code for creating the group is perfect. But I don't think you should dispose the RootWeb object created from SPContext.Current.Site. Details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557362(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: RJ Cuthbertson's answer is closer to how I'd want things to work - after creating a group you also want to associate it to a site, and this is done by using the SPRoleDefinition/SPRoleAssignment combo.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to @RJ Cuthbertson 's answer to avoid empty try/catch block when testing whether group with that name has already been created:

```
SPGroup group = w.SiteGroups.Cast<SPGroup>().SingleOrDefault(g => g.Name == "The Group Name");

// If it doesn't, add it
if (group == null)
{
    root.SiteGroups.Add("The Group Name", member, root.Author, "Your Group Description");
    group = root.SiteGroups["The Group Name"];

    // Add the group's permissions
    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = root.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
    root.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    root.Update();
}
```